# Upsert Option in ADF Copy Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

With the "`upsert` option" , should I expect to see "**0**" as "`Rows Written`" in a copy activity result summary?
My situation is this: The source and sink table columns are **not** exactly the same but the Key columns to tell it how to know the write behavior are correct.
I have tested and made sure that it does actually do insert or update based on the data I give to it BUT what I don't understand is if I make ZERO changes and just keep running the pipeline , why does it not show "zero" in the `Rows Written` summary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upsert only updates the record if it is present in both source and target tables and inserts if not present in the target and present in source.

Not sure why in the above answer it was mentioned that "*it is modifying all records irrespective of the changes in data.*" and it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why rowsWritten is not shown as `0` even when the source and destination have same data is:

- `Upsert` inserts data when a key column value is absent in target table and updates the values of other rows whenever the key column is found in target table.
- Hence, it is modifying all records irrespective of the changes in data. As in SQL `Merge`, there is no way to tell copy activity that if an entire row already exists in target table, then ignore that case.
- So, even when `key_column` matches, it is going to update the values for rest of the columns and hence **counted as row written**. The following is an example of 2 cases

**The rows of source and sink are same:**

- The rows present:

```
id,gname
1,Ana
2,Ceb
3,Topias
4,Jerax
6,Miracle
```

[image]

**When inserting completely new rows:**

- The rows present in source are (where sink data is as above):

```
id,gname
8,Sumail
9,ATF
```

[image]

Comment: WHAAAAT ! So what's the point of an UPSERT then if it is going to overwrite the data in all columns anyway ? I thought we say ok this column matches because my unique key matches so do not touch the other values in the column

Comment: Upsert generally indicates that Update if and insert if. In copy data, both are done just based on key column without any additional conditions. You can use Dataflows for extended functionality where you can use `alter row` transformation to say when to update (provide additional conditions as well) so that it wont touch other column values when key column matches

Comment: @SaideepArikontham is there a way to get the count of updated vs inserted rows from a copy activity?